# How to get clicked index of input array?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have this html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheck[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheck[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheck[]" value="3" />
```

If I have this jQuery code:

```
$('input[name="mycheck"]').change(function() {
    alert("which checkbox index I checked");
}
```

Assuming the indexes are 0 based I should have 0, 1, 2 How do I get it to alert "1" when I click the middle checkbox?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  $("input[name='mycheck[]']").change(function() {
        alert($(this).index());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.. I tried this but didn't keep the brackets. I see it works with brackets

Answer (score 2):

There is an [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method for that

```
$('input').change(function() {
    alert($(this).index());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6UfV7/

Comment: hmm I'm sure I tried this.. but I think I was using the core name and not the name with the brackets.. thx I'll try it again.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`.index()` method](http://api.jquery.com/index).

```
$('input[name="mycheck[]"]').change(function() {
    var index = $('input[name="mycheck[]"]').index(this);
    alert(index);
});
```

But you also need to target `mycheck[]` instead of `mycheck` as that is how you have named your elements.

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/K9CF2/1/

Comment: Yea.. I realize now I was missing the brackets when I tried this last. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Asuming the numbers go like 1,2,3,4, and so on, you could simply do that:

```
alert($(this).val()-1);
```

[or that](http://jsfiddle.net/392bc/):

```
alert($(this).index());
```

And also, you have to select the entire name:

```
$('input[name="mycheck[]"]')
```